# Probability Calculation

Tags: php, javascript

I have something like this in my website: There are grids, members click them randomly, they view a webpage, then they learn if they won a prize or not. They have limited number of chance daily.

My algorithm to calculate prize win probability:

1. Randomly select a number between 1 and 10,000
   1a. if this number equals to 1 member wins X
   1b. if this number =< 5 member wins Y etc.

Is there another way to calculate this or should I control prizes with additional codes (for example: if today x member won y amount prize stop giving prizes)?

Thanks.

Comment: You have two different issues here: 1. has the user won the prize? 2. are any prizes left for today? It is not really clear what the problem is...

Comment: @logi: How is this possible 1a and 1b? Do you have multiple members for a number?

Comment: I think there's a million other ways to calculate this. choose whatever you wish.

Comment: @Chibox: I think he means that with 1 you win the higher prize, 2,3,4 or 5 you win the second prize, >5 you lose

Comment: @nico: A logarithmic distribution? Log(random(100))*10?

Comment: Thanks for replies. I think I could not make my myself clear. All I want is after a member clicks they must have:  very very very little chance to win big prize, very very little chance to win second big prize, very little chance to win third big prize and little chance to win a prize. But I don't want a daily limit for prizes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several other ways to calculate this, but your idea is good enough. You can use the following pseudocode for assistance also:

```
int randomnumber = generaterandomnumber();
bool allprizesgone = getinformationfromdatabase();
if ( allprizesgone equals false ) {
    if(randomnumber equals 1) {
        member wins X
        if(checkifallprizesfortodayaretakes() equals true) {
            setinformationtodatabase(allprizesgonetrue);
        }
    } else if (randomnumer is smaller than 5 ){ //because of else if members can't get both prizes
       member wins Y
       if(checkifallprizesfortodayaretakes() equals true) {
            setinformationtodatabase(allprizesgonetrue);
        }
    }

}
```